# Using C# RFID package with Java

Tags: c#, java, java-native-interface, rfid

I am looking to access a FX7400 RFID reader with a Java application, unfortunately the only developer kits they offer for the reader are .NET and C. Is there an easy way for me to access the functions in the developer kit by somehow linking java and C#?

Comment: Are you trying to use LLRP or the Motorola specific apis?  For LLRP, try http://www.llrp.org

Comment: I am trying to use the Motorola specific apis.

Comment: You could use JNI to access the C library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when it was added, but there is currently a [EMDK FOR .NET](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Software+and+Applications/Mobility+Software/Mobile+Application+Utilities/EMDT-EMCT_US-EN) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Motorola has released at the end of august an [EMDK for Java RFID](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=13269&sliceId=&dialogID=257050854&stateId=1%200%20257044578):

The Java RFID class library supports the following feature:

1. Connection Management (Open/Close connection to the reader)
2. Configuration
        1. Antenna
        2. RF Mode
        3. Singulation
3. Inventory
        1. Simple
        2. Trigger Based (Start & Stop)
4. Access (Both Synchronous and Asynchronous)
        1. Read
        2. Write
        3. Lock
        4. Kill
        5. Block Erase
        6. Block Perma Lock
        7. Access sequence
5. Filter
        1. Pre-Filter
        2. Access Filter
        3. Post Filter
6. RM (Reader Management) APIs
7. NXP Tag support
8. Tag Locationing

Answer (score 0):

Motorola has SDK for FX7400 rfid reader named "EMDK FOR JAVA".
inside of this sdk there is an rfid example for fx7400. You run this ex on eclipse(java program) this program can connect, read, write, and has alot of classes for rfid. you can check this for java code.